# babel: babel@toc causing problem

Tags: babel

- I have a bilingual document.
- The main language is English.
- Throughout the document, I switch between the two languages.
- **I have noticed that `babel` writes language-specific commands in the toc file (e. g. `\babel@toc {english}{}`).**
- I provide an artificial MWE, see below. The actual document is Chinese and English.
- **Where the trouble begins...:** In my real use case I use `\today` in the footline of the document.
- **Problem:** In the footline of the toc chapter, the `\today` command produces (randomly) different outputs (language-specific).
- **Question:** Can I prevent that `\babel@toc` is written to the toc file?

---

Content of the `toc` file.

```
\babel@toc {english}{}
\babel@toc {english}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}English}{1}% 
\babel@toc {spanish}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}Spanish}{1}% 
\babel@toc {english}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3}English}{1}%
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish, english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

%% English -------------------------
\selectlanguage{english}

\section{English}

Test \today

%% Spanish -------------------------
\selectlanguage{spanish}

\section{Spanish}

Test \today

%% English -------------------------
\selectlanguage{english}

\section{English}

Test \today

\end{document}
```

---

Even when I use

```
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
    Text.
\end{otherlanguage}
```

and

```
\begin{otherlanguage}{spanish}
    Text.
\end{otherlanguage}
```

the problem occurs.

Comment: that is the wrong question. You don't want to prevent the commands in the toc but to force the right language in the footline. Use `\selectlanguage{english}\today` there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! I was just surprised that this has not caused other questions until now (at least I did not find any). It took me a while to understand the side effect that caused my weird observation :).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solven in comments.